# Ubuntu Machine sharing internet, but won't show up on network

Tags: networking, internet, modem

I get my home internet through a hotspot, which is limited to 10 devices and has a horrific wireless range. To bypass these limitations, I am using a laptop running Ubuntu connected to a wireless router.

Set-Up is this:

Hotspot --> Ubuntu Machine (wifi) --> Shared Internet over Ethernet --> Wi-Fi Router --> Rest of devices in the house. Essentially, the Ubuntu machine is acting as a modem and feeding internet to the router.

This is been working great, other than the router telling me it is experiencing a double NAT. I've ignored the issue yet far and no problems have arisen.

The problem I cannot figure out is that the Ubuntu machine is not visible on the whole house Wi-Fi. I am also using the Ubuntu Machine as an AirPrint server for my iDevices, and the only way I can connect to that server is by connecting to the hotspot. Is there something in Ubuntu I am missing that will allow the machine to not only act as a modem but simultaneously as a machine on the network?

Thanks!

Bonus points if you can fix the NAT issue too :)

Comment: What do you mean by "not visible"?

Comment: No, there's no way. Either the machine is in the LAN -or- acting as a hotspot. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: @LasVegasCoder, No other device I have can see the laptop. The AirPrint server running on it works if I connect to the hotspot wifi (and in turn join the same network as the ubuntu laptop), but if I am on the SSID of the router getting its internet connection from the Ubuntu laptop, I cannot see the AirPrint Server, or see it listed in a list of networked computers.

Comment: >(and in turn join the same network as the ubuntu laptop) ***using the same WiFi-card used to receive and transmit data from the **hotspot**? *** Your WiFi Card is already occupied transmitting data from your hotstop *** ─in use.  **Try to create a virtual machine and connect from there.**

Answer (score 0):

## How to fix Double Nat

> Double NAT is a scenario where multiple routers on network are doing
> network address translation. Common example is a Cable or DSL modem,
> to which a Wi-Fi router is connected. Both modem and router have NAT
> enabled. Computers on the network are connected to Wi-Fi router

### Example: Turn off NAT on AirPort Base Station.

If you use an AirPort Base Station, follow these steps to turn off NAT:
Choose Go > Utilities from the menu bar, then open AirPort Utility.
Select your base station and click Edit in the pop-up menu.
Click the Network tab, then choose "Off (Bridge mode)" from the Router menu.
Click Update to restart the base station.

Alternatively you may use console and command lines to turn off your NAT.

Possible Solutions:

### Setup a PPPoE Connection Between Your Wireless Router & Modem

*PPPoE can be usually setup in your wireless router's WAN settings.*

If your wireless router support **PPPoE**, you will find multiple options to configure the WAN connection of wireless router, such as:

- DHCP
- PPPoE

### DHCP

If you are still reading, the chance that you are using DHCP to connect to internet from your router is about 95+%.  *There's nothing bad with that, but not the best option.*

> Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) is a protocol for assigning
> dynamic IP addresses to devices on a network. With dynamic addressing,
> a device can have a different IP address every time it connects to the
> network.

DHCP is the best option because it results in private IP address assigned to the WiFi router.

### PPPoE

> PPPoE stands for Point-to-Point Protocol over Ethernet, a network
> protocol for encapsulating Point-to-Point Protocol (PPP) frames inside
> Ethernet frames. It is used mainly with DSL services where individual
> users connect to a DSL modem over Ethernet

PPPoE is a better choice, because it bypasses the NAT settings in the modem and connect directly to your *Internet Service Provider* **(ISP)**.

**Setup**

Login into your router using your router gateway IP Address e.g 192.168.0.1. *(IP Address and procedures below may vary slightly)*

- Login into your router
- Goto Connection/Network Settings
- Goto WAN Setting
- **Choose PPPoE**.
- Save

### Bridge

> When referring to computers, a bridge is a device that connects two
> local-area networks (LANs), or two segments of the same LAN. Unlike a
> router, bridges are protocol -independent. They forward packets
> without analyzing and re-routing messages.

**Set Your Wireless router bridged mode ON.**

*Bridged mode on wireless router means that NAT and DHCP functions on it will be disabled.*

- Goto Connection/Network Setup
- Switch BRIDGE MODE to ON
- Save

NOTE: Not all routers support *Bridge Mode*, some routers be may referring to *Bridge Mode* as **Disable DHCP in the router configuration**

Hope this helps.

Comment: *“some may refer to Bridge Mode as Disable DHCP”* have any source, because that sounds like complete nonsense?